# How to keep the code style and reformat consistent between idea and STS?

Tags: git, eclipse, intellij-idea

i'm use idea for development,others use STS and eclipse. when i pull their code and reformat, git will report a lot of differences, but i can't see the difference at all. Is there any way to keep the code style of diea consistent with eclipse？ I tried to import the formatter of eclipse, but the result did not change. My leader warned me not to use idea unless this problem is solved, please helo me, i really don't want to use STS for development!

Comment: Do you have the Eclipse XML Profile file? Importing it would be the easiest solution. Need to understand why it does not take effect. Manual configuration is always a way.

Comment: Are there any technical reasons for [limiting](https://twitter.com/sandeep07_dev/status/1434929178600566790) [yourself](https://twitter.com/MGrzejszczak/status/1435573325862948868) and bothering your colleagues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use the [Eclipse Code Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter) ([GitHub project](https://github.com/krasa/EclipseCodeFormatter#instructions)), since the official [Eclipse settings import](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/01/intellij-idea-13-importing-code-formatter-settings-from-eclipse/) feature might not be complete or without bugs.

Check if the formatting is better supporting with the plugin.